# if folder exists, return true

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I can check if a folder is empty.

```
this.emptyfolder = function(folderid) {
    result = PlacesUtils.getFolderContents(folderid);
    resultContainerNode = result.root;
    if (resultContainerNode.ChildCount == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How to check if a folder exists even if it's empty?

- [link to the PlacesUtils description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Places_utilities_for_JavaScript)
- [link to the PlacesUtils code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/places/src/PlacesUtils.jsm)

Comment: If you can positively check that a folder is empty, don't you then also know it exists? If a folder doesn't exist, can it be empty? Can a non-existent folder contain a file?

Comment: When you create a folder, it'll be there, but without any bookmark yet.

Answer (score 1):

many bookmarks service methods will throw if and item id does not exist, so for example PlacesUtils.bookmarks.getItemType(itemId); will throw.
But actually, I'm missing your use-case, when working with folders you usually work with views, and you the don't bother about the fact a certain item id exists.